# Override Json.net behaviour to take more attributes into account

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to use Json.net to serialize my object to the client side, which it does brilliantly.  However I want to extend it's behaviour to use more attributes during serialization, specifically attributes from the Data Annotations namespace.

Here's one example:
I need to output a date, and rather than send the date to the client side, and format it there, I want to control the format of the output on the server side.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime BirthDate { get;set;}
```

I looked at using a converter to process this, but at the stage a converter is executed, it has no reference back to the member information of the declaring property, so I wouldn't be able to examine the attribute.  I'm assuming I would need to override/extend the IContractResolver behaviour, but there is very little documentation on how all the pieces fit, like JsonContract etc.

I just need some pointers as to how the whole thing hangs together, and I'll work the rest out.  Thanks in advance to anyone kind enough to assist.